# Distinct UITableViewCell / UICollectionViewCell metrics between iPhone 6 Plus and all other smaller screens

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, size-classes

I have an iOS app that currently supports all screen sizes of iPhone and iPod touch (but not iPad), only in portrait orientation. The app supports iOS 7 and newer. My visual designer suggested increasing some metrics within certain `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` instances when displaying on the iPhone 6 Plus. For example, the image cell that shows an icon or a contact photo will be about 25% larger (by points) only on iPhone 6 Plus.

After reading [this Adaptive Size Design article at apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html), I see that iPhone 6 Plus does not have a distinct size class from smaller screen devices when in portrait orientation. Does this mean that I should detect the screen resolution and handle the iPhone 6 Plus-specific metrics in code instead of the xib? Or is there a way to handle this in the xib that I haven't come across yet?

In code, I could easily specify an alternate xib to load for iPhone 6 Plus, but would prefer to only have one xib to support all screen sizes and scale factors. This app might support iPads in the future, but not right now.

Comment: You can also use AutoLayout in the xib to achieve that.

Comment: I will use autolayout, but I first need to provide a custom cell size for the iPhone 6 Plus. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: if you wish to display a distinct UI on the 6+ in portrait, you're going to have to do it programmatically, either by using UIScreen or UIDevice to identify when you're running on that hardware.